# Changing the way authors' names are displayed in a citation?

Tags: bibliographies

For example, currently if I do a `\cite{name}` I get this:

(AUTHOR1, 2000)
(AUTHOR1; AUTHOR2, 2000)
(AUTHOR1; AUTHOR2; AUTHOR3, 2000)

What I'd like is to have et al. beyond 2 authors and have "and" when there are just 2. So:

(AUTHOR1, 2000)
(AUTHOR1 and AUTHOR2, 2000)
(AUTHOR1 et al., 2000)

Is it possible to get that?

I've found these packages being imported by the model:

```
\usepackage[bibjustif,abnt-etal-cite=3,abnt-full-initials=yes]{abntcite}
\usepackage[toc,page]{modelo/tex/appendix}
\usepackage[portuguese,brazilian,portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{abnt-alf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
```

If I edit the `abnt-etal-cite=2` I can get the et al. as I need, but what about the separator between 2 authors names?

Comment: You must be loading some package to get citations in that form: the LaTeX default does not do that. Please provide more detail.

Comment: Oh man I'm a total noob. How do I check that?

Comment: Two possibles. You might be using a customise class (the part that goes after `\documentclass`), so the name of your class would be helpful. The other possibility is that you are loading a package to alter the behaviour. The obvious choices are `natbib` and `biblatex`. Have you got either of those listed as `\usepackage{...}`?

Comment: "I've found these packages being imported by the model:" The model? To what do you refer?

Comment: I'm using a model to write a paper. Well, I thought I was at least.

Comment: I've run across `abntcite` before: I'm not hopeful of a solution without switching to `natbib` or `biblatex`!

Comment: I replaced the `{cite}` tag with `{bibliographies}` because this is a question about general bibliography/citation styles, not about custom `\cite` commands.

Answer (score 5):

The package abntcite is not available on CTAN. According to [this discussion](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&p=9743), the package and/or the accompanying style files were somewhat faulty two years ago. I suggest that you use the package [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) instead, which handles author names the way you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=2]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Aut10a,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2010},
  title = {And now for something completely different},
}

@misc{Aut10b,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
  year = {2010},
  title = {And now for something completely different},
}

@misc{Aut10c,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2010},
  title = {And now for something completely different},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\parencite{Aut10a}

\parencite{Aut10b}

\parencite{Aut10c}

% Name cap also in bibliography
\printbibliography

% No name cap in bibliography
\printbibliography[maxnames=99]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking out the `\usepackage[bibjustif,abnt-etal-cite=3,abnt-full-initials=yes]{abntcite}` and putting somewhere `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`. That should work. Also, try loading `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` and using the command `\citep{ }` for cites in parenthesis and `\citet{ }` for textual cites.